# Razor pages - Change page name depending on the culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm building a Razor web application using .NET6 and I have 3 different cultures.
For SEO purpose, I'm trying to have a page name who's different depending from the culture.

Like for example:

en: https://www.website.com/en/contact-us
fr: https://www.website.com/fr/contactez-nous

I found a cool article about friendly routes but it has to be done via .AddPageRoute in the Pipeline and I don't see how could I make it match depending on the culture (like one for each culture).
I tried this but it looks like it only take care of the last one:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Contact", "/contact-us");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Contact", "/contactez-nous");
```

**This is my Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
        {
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template);
            }
        });
    });
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opt =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
        new CultureInfo("nl")
    };
    opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
    opt.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    opt.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    opt.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider()
    {
        RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
        UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
        Options = opt
    });
});

builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.LowercaseUrls = true;
    opt.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

var options = ((IApplicationBuilder)app).ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**Contact.cshtml**

```
@page "/Contact"
@model client.Pages.Contact
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div>
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="ContactModel.FullName" placeholder="Full name">
            <span asp-validation-for="ContactModel.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" asp-for="ContactModel.Email" placeholder="info@developify.be">
            <span asp-validation-for="ContactModel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea asp-for="ContactModel.Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="ContactModel.Message" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Anchor from _Layout.cshtml**

```
<a class="" asp-area="" asp-page="/Contact"
                        asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name">Contact</a>
```

How can I achieve this? Do I have to do something with the selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template?

Comment: " have a page name who's different depending from the culture" Do you mean just the title use Localization? Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#view-localization).

Comment: @QingGuo I mean the "@page name" -> or the url if it's more precise :-)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/BrightSoul/aspnetcore-localization-demo) is a mvc core3.1 demo that can meet your need, you can refer to it , hope it will useful .

Comment: Is it going to work since it use Controllers while I only use Razor pages?

Comment: You should be able to check CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo to do what you need, ensure it is set correctly though, there are several levels of setting the culture in the startup file in .net such as  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use url rewrite as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#extension-and-options

That way, every page is mapped to its english spelled route. Translations are rewritten to the english version by the specified rewrite options.